# Change account details in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Using VBA I know it's possible to change the sender account for the emails using `.SendUsingAccount`

Is it possible to use a single sender account but change the account details just using VBA?

Eg changing an existing email address, server, port, SSL etc without adding a new account.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the "From" email header is one of the possible solutions: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14.

You can also change the account details using Redemption (I am its author): http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm